# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Entry cannot be deleted

Tags: java, api, youtube

According to the Google Youtube Java API if I want to delete a video, first is to get the VideoEntry Object, then call it's delete;

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

Document says to retrieve a specific video entry:

```
//My own function returns me the service Obj, and it works!
YouTubeService service =  getYoutubeService(); 
String videoEntryUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/MyVideoID";
VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryUrl), VideoEntry.class);
```

But when I call delet, it gives me the exception

```
videoEntry.delete();
```

Any now, I have to get the feeds, then loop through the videoFeed.getEntries() List to find the VideoEntry has the same videoID as I passed in.

```
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL( "http://gdata.youtube.com/feed/api/users/My Account/uploads"), VideoFeed.class);
```

Why the VideoEntry Obj in videoFeed.getEntries() List can call delete() function but not the VideoEntry Obj returned by service.getEntry function ????

Comment: http://osdir.com/ml/youtube-api-gdata/2010-01/msg00122.html ?

Comment: and there's more on http://groups.jonzu.com/z_tag/delete/page/3/

Comment: Yes, Thanks! It's actually my urls fault! I should set the url to my account directory then I could delete the video by the video ID Cheers!!

Comment: I'll add that as the answer, so I can get upvoted then. Please accep t my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[osdir.com/ml/youtube-api-gdata/2010-01/msg00122.html](http://%20osdir.com/ml/youtube-api-gdata/2010-01/msg00122.html)
and there's more on [groups.jonzu.com/z_tag/delete/page/3](http://%20osdir.com/ml/youtube-api-gdata/2010-01/msg00122.html)

imply the URL needs to be set to your account directory.